# Python IDLE Unable to Be Opened

Tags: python, python-idle

## A little context

I'm using Windows. I installed Python and wrote a script for it. Before long, it became necessary to install packages. To do so, I needed to know what was the location of my Python folder, so that I could enter this location in the command prompt as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKwicZF7xNE) at 7:55. My idea for how to achieve this was to go into the "This PC" app (as in, enter the words "This PC" into the search bar which is next to the start symbol in the lower left-hand (LLH) corner of the screen) and search within that app the phrase "Python" (as in, enter "Python" into the search bar which is in the URH corner of the window which is opened when the symbol "This PC" is clicked). Then, I just made a new folder titled 'Python 3.7' on my desktop and dragged all of the search results into that new folder.

---

## Slightly more detailed explanation of the problem

Now, everything can be found in that folder, and I find it to be reasonably organized, but most things no longer function if I attempt to click on them. For example, clicking on the 'IDLE (Python 3.7 32-bit)' shortcut has no effect whatsoever. The shortcut which I have pinned to my taskbar also inexplicably no longer does anything when it is clicked. Going to the .py script I wrote, right clicking, and selecting "Open" has no effect; on that same menu, selecting "edit with IDLE" opens a window asking "How do you want to open this .py file?" I select the option "Python" and click OK, and nothing happens.

---

## What I expect to be the most relevant information

The thing titled 'IDLE (Python 3.7 32-bit)' which I click on is categorized as a Shortcut. When I right-click and go into the properties, it says the Target Location is

> Python37-32

which is a folder. It further says Target:

> \Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw"

and Start in:

> "C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Python 3.7\python\Python37-32\"

whereas the current location of the Shortcut is

> C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Python 3.7

Essentially, I have rearranged folders without much thought, and inadvertently messed something up?

Does someone happen to know, at least, what this issue is - or, perhaps, to be so gracious as to refer me to a help page on the subject - so that I may research the issue?

Comment: yeah, basically don't mess up with installations, they are in a specific place for a reason, the dragging changed the path of `python` and now the `system` can't find it. Consider uninstalling `python`, deleting that folder and installing it again.

Comment: That's definitely doable. Is it really that hard for the program to figure out what folder a shortcut is located in?

Comment: It is windows looking for the program in a folder that it listed in a different place in the registry. So yes Windows has no idea where it is and that is why you are having such a headache.
Note this can happen in MAC, Linux, and any other operating system.  Accidental moving or overwriting of PATHs in the filesystem can wreck havoc.